# Multiple Clickable Zones in ListView Items?

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem, android-seekbar

I need to be able to manage a seekbar and a switch that are part of an item which is inside a ListView. How can I control these elements, getting and changing their values?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: 1. Should I declare these elements and methods for them in my class that displays the listView or in the adapter? Nothing happens when I click the switch or slide the seekbar